# How to implementation wechat provider in SecureSocial?

Tags: securesocial, wechat

SecureSocial is an authentication module for Play Framework applications that works with services based on `OAuth1, OAuth2 and OpenID*`.

It provides out of the box support for:

```
Twitter (OAuth1)
Facebook (OAuth2)
GitHub (OAuth2)
Google (OAuth2)
LinkedIn (OAuth1 and OAuth2)
Foursquare (OAuth2)
Instagram (OAuth2)
VK (OAuth2)
XING (OAuth1)
Username/Password with signup and reset password functionality.
```

How to implement wechat  provider in SecureSocial?

Answer (score 0):

WeChat basically has Access-token based authentication only if the account is verified.

You can refer the wiki of [Weixin](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki)

If you want to follow Access-Token based, problem is openid of same user will different for different official account but the unionid will be same for the user even the user follows multiple account.

WeChat also provide OAuth2 protocol. For this you need to have a account in [OPEN WEIXIN](https://open.weixin.qq.com/) once you have that you will be able to follow this procedure 
[OAuth2 Wechat](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=User_Profile_via_Web)

We have built a application called wechatify a overlay of wechat platform.